# Updating the Shipping Carrier on a Netsuite Customer Record

Tags: netsuite

Just as a test to see if it worked on one record I created the following mass update script and it doesn't seem to be updating the record I am telling it to but I get no errors. What am I doing wrong?

```
function shipCarrier(rec_type) {
    var recid=11952;
    var cust=nlapiLoadRecord(rec_type, recid);
    cust.setFieldValue('shippingcarrier','UPS');
    nlapiSubmitRecord(cust);
}
```

Comment: what does `nlapiSubmitRecord(cust)` return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I change your code to use cust.setFieldText() rather than cust.setFieldValue(), it works for me as a mass update script.

setFieldValue() is looking for the integer ID of the UPS item rather than the text.

Comment: For me, shipcarrier on a new sales order defaults to UPS. The other option in the list is "More". I'm using salesOrder.setFieldText('shipcarrier', 'More') and get no error but the outcome is that the record is created with UPS selected. Please can you help?

Comment: It depends on where your code is executing and what other code/workflows might be running.  Is it possible that another user event script or workflow is running after your code that is setting the field to 'UPS'?  You can check script order of execution by navigating to Customization -> Scripts -> Scripted Record -> Sales Order.  This will show you all scripts and workflows that are deployed on sales orders.